# LVM -> dd -> LVM?

Tags: lvm, dd

I've 'cloned' a LVM partition using dd over ssh to a remote server(emergency backup...).

On that remote server, is it possible to 'transform' the dd cloned file back into a LVM partition?

Thanks.

PS: I can access the filesystem on the cloned file, but I don't want a solution which includes rsync or something similar.

Comment: I'm not answering because I'm not sure, but doesn't LVM2 have GUIDs for LVs? In which case they would have to be relabeled...

Comment: "LVM partition" == LV or PV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think what you would want to do would be one of the following:

1. Mount the `dd` image over loopback.
2. Rewrite a real disk with the dd image and mount it.

Then, you'll want to "redetect" the LVM config by running:

```
pvscan
vgscan -ay
lvscan
```

This is what I've done with EBS clones but not `dd` clones; but hopefully it also works, it's the same theory.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, do you think there is a solution like the one @Joris described in the comments of the first answer?

The partition is not a pv but a lv.

Comment: If the image is a LV, with no partition table, you could mount it through a loopback. But if the image has a partition table, you would have to use kpartx. Either way, there is no need to mount it to dd the image / partition.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should create an LVM that is at least the same size of the original one. Then you can do something like:

```
local# dd if=/dev/vglocal/lvm-old | ssh remote dd of=/dev/vgremote/lvm-new
```

And that should do it. If you already have a file with the original lvm on the remote server, then something very similar can be done:

```
remote# dd if=/path/to/img of=/dev/vgremote/lvm-new
```

You could also add the option `bs` to increment the blocksize used by dd, to speed up the process:

```
# dd if=... of=... bs=131072
```

Comment: Can't you losetup the file to a device and then have lvm recognise the pv?

Comment: If this is a physical volume and just for the purpose of reading its contents, you could. But I dont see the point of it if you have already set up a volume group, in which you can fense this partition growth, take a snapshot, and above all, do not use abstraction layer over abstraction layers, which might result in punitive performance.